# Mouse hover element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html code like this:

```
<div class="tree-node" node-id="71408acd-931e-42c8-98fa-393271006cf9" style="cursor: pointer;">
<span class="tree-hit tree-collapsed"></span>
<span class="tree-icon tree-folder icon-hospital"></span>
<span class="tree-checkbox tree-checkbox1"></span>
<span class="tree-title">
<a href="/Structure/EditHospital/71408acd-931e-42c8-98fa-393271006cf9">Hospital1</a>
(1/1)
</span>
</div>
```

I would like to change cursor  when mouse hover this element, show `pointer` if  `<span class="tree-title">` constainse `a href` and `default`, if no.

Comment: is the container `<span class="tree-title">` dynamic? I mean that sometime it contains `<a>` inside and sometimes not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.tree-title').each(function () {
   if ($(this).find('a[href]').length) {
      $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
   }
});
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cQ7xC/)

Comment: It took me ten seconds to figure out why you weren't using `:hover`. My bad. @revolutionkpi: you can't get any better than this answer. +1

Comment: I know that I shoude use this property, tahnks, but I is  a bit difficult to select this element

Comment: It doesn't select element for which I will use this property. I try: $("span.tree-title").on('hover', function() {
 alert($(this).html());

Comment: I add this content dynamicaly. so the question is how to select and then change this property